# Modificar EditText con Selector de Fechas

Tags: java, android

Cómo puedo hacer para que cuando marque una fecha en el Selector de Fechas se añada al EditText?

Código que uso para el Selector de Fechas:

```
private void setAlarm(Uri passuri){

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(datePicker.getYear(),
            datePicker.getMonth(),
            datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
            timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
            timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
            00);
```

EDIT: @Keops

```
    private void setAlarm(Uri passuri){

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(datePicker.getYear(),
                datePicker.getMonth(),
                datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
                timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
                00);

        String formatoFecha = "d/MM/yyyy";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoFecha);
        String date = df.format(cal.getTime());

        editTextFecha.setText(date);

        String passString = passuri.toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), otrointento.prueba.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("KEY_TONE_URL", passString);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext(),
                RQS_1,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto:

```
private void setAlarm(Uri passuri){

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(datePicker.getYear(),
        datePicker.getMonth(),
        datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
        timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
        timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
        00);

       String formatoFecha = "EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm";
       DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(formatoFecha);
       String date = df.format(cal.getTime());

       editText.setText(date);
}
```

Para lanzar a tu Calendar debes implementa el click listener en tu EditText:

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Aqui invocas a tu calendario 
        invocaCalendario();
    }
});
```

En tu layout, a tu EditText añade la siguiente línea para permitir el touch

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Código para tu calendario

```
    public void invocaCalendario(){
        Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
        int anio =mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mes =mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dia=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog mDatePicker=new DatePickerDialog(MiActivity.this, new OnDateSetListener() {                  
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {

                // Tu código
            }
        },anio, mes, dia);
        mDatePicker.setTitle("Selecciona Fecha");                
        mDatePicker.show();  }

  }
```

Comment: Gracias @Keops lo probaré y comento, lo quiero usar para las alarmas, para así guardar la fecha en la database sqlite

Comment: Muchas gracias @Keops funciona perfectamente, pero si puede ser me podrías decir como hacer para que el calendario solamente saliese al pulsar sobre el EditText? para no abrir otra pregunta, muchas gracias !

Comment: @UserNameYo edite mi respuesta con la pulsación del EditText

Comment: Invoco "setAlarm(Uri passuri)" pero me da dos errores "illegal start of expression" y "error ')' expected @Keops

Comment: @UserNameYo verifica que no te falte un punto y coma

Comment: he añadido una captura al primer comentario a ver si ves el error, si invoco setAlarm(uriAlarm); no da errores, pero lo que hace es crear la alarma, no abrir el calendario

Comment: @UserNameYo Agrega el código de tu calendario

Comment: lo acabo de añadir al primer comentario, tengo el calendario en el layout, pero quiero quitarlo de ahí y que solo salga al pulsar en el edittext

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51338/discussion-between-keops-and-usernameyo).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar guardando los datos en enteros y pasarlos al campo de esta manera:

```
    private Edittext texto;
    private int datePickerAnio;
    private int datePickerMes;
    private int datePickerDia;
    private int hora;
    private int minuto;



final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            datePickerAnio = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            datePickerMes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            datePickerDia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            hora = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
            minuto = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

mostrarFecha();

private void mostrarFecha() {
        texto.setText(
            new StringBuilder()

                    .append(datePickerDia ).append("-")
                    .append(datePickerMes + 1).append("-")
                    .append(datePickerAnio ).append(" "));
    }
```

Comment: ¿? No mencionas eso en tu pregunta, haz otra nueva con eso o bien edita tu pregunta.